# Soft-Wrap Editor in Android Studio 3.5.1

Tags: android-studio

Older versions of Android Studio had option "Use soft wraps in editor"

But now I can't find it there:

[image]

There is only option "Soft-Wrap Current Editor" which I always have to enable for every opened editor tab

Older versions:

[image]

I tried to add `*.xml, *.kt` to a new option "Soft-wrap files" but nothing changes

Comment: I'm having the same problem. New computer, newly installed Android Studio, and I can't figure out how to get it to wrap long Java comments. Such a basic feature.

Answer (score 0):

It works, my problem was just that I used to separate file paterns commas instead of semicolons.

Try change **`,`** into **`;`**.

For example `*.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc; *.java`